# PHP ODBC Running 2 queries error

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have a php file that im using odbc to get data from MSSQL 2008. I got everything working; however, when I try to run another query after the first one I get this error:

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt, SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\wamp\www\3.php on line 7

```
if ($conn)
{
//there will be no return output for this one just want to run it to refresh the sales data
  $query1="my query code here"; 
  $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query1);

  $query2="my other query code here"; 
  $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query2);

}
```

Comment: Now I got it to work by running one <?PHP query one, close connection ?> then opening the connection again and running the other, it works perfectly; however isnt it not practical to open and close connections when you dont have to or can I just leave it like that.

Comment: you should be able do use `odbc_free_result` after using the first result set, instead of closing the connection.

Comment: : Use of undefined constant odbc_free_result - assumed 'odbc_free_result' in C:\wamp\www\3.php on line 26

Comment: odbc_free_result(); thats what I added in my code. Its not working still Warning: odbc_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in C:\wamp\www\3.php on line 26

Comment: nevermind I fixed it its: odbc_free_result($result);

Comment: I know this is pretty much answered at this point, but I wanted to point out the cause to go along with the resolution.

I believe the Microsoft ODBC SQL Server driver is a single statement per connection driver.

This means that there can be no pending results for a statement before another statement is executed.

In your case, you executed the statement which creates a pending resultset.  Then when you attempt to execute the second statement, the error occurs.

Clearing the statement by either fetching all of the data or freeing the result set will work.

Comment: Thank you for the deep explanation, its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I post this in another question and I think could be useful to you.

```
function foo($sql){
   $res = odbc_exec($this->dbconn, $sql);
   if (odbc_error () and $res===false ) {
       throw new Exception odbc_errormsg($this->dbconn));

   }
    return $res;
}
```